# Convert nonlinear objective function to linear objective function

Tags: gams-math

Right now, I am using GAMS solver to maximize the objective function (**maximization of the Total Average Capacity Utilization**) written below:

objFunction..  G =E=  sum((i,j), X(i,j)/caprepaircenter(j)) / sum(j, Z(j));

In the objFunction;

- X(i,j) gives the return volume from collection center i to repair center j 
  (X(i,j) >= 0),
- caprepaircenter(j) gives the capacity of each repair center j, and
- Z(j) gives the establishment decision of repair center j (binary decision variable/ if repair center j is open then Z(j) = 1, else Z(j) = 0).

However, I want to have a linear objective function instead of a nonlinear one in the GAMS code. So, how can I convert the nonlinear objective function (written above) to linear ?

Answer (score 0):

If X(i,j), caprepaircenter(j) and Z(j) are all variables, then there is not really a way to convert your objective function as a linear function, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, X(i,j) and Z(j) are variables whereas caprepaircenter(j) is a parameter. In this case, is there any way to convert this nonlinear function to linear one?

Answer (score 0):

The equation

```
G =E= sum((i,j), X(i,j)/caprepaircenter(j)) / sum(j, Z(j))
```

can be written as

```
sum(j, G*Z(j)) =E= sum((i,j), X(i,j)/caprepaircenter(j))
```

This again can be written as:

```
sum(j, y(j)) =E= sum((i,j), X(i,j)/caprepaircenter(j)) 
y(j) = G*Z(j)
```

The products `y(j) = G*Z(j)` are `continuous variable * binary variable`. This can be linearized as shown [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html).

[Here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/05/linearizing-average.html) is a similar model where this trick is applied.